# How can I check if an array element exists?

Tags: php

Example: I'm checking for the existence of an array element like this:

```
if (!self::$instances[$instanceKey]) {
    $instances[$instanceKey] = $theInstance;
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: test in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/MyClass.php on line 16

Of course, the first time I want an instance, $instances will not know the key. I guess my check for available instance is wrong?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can use either the language construct [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset), or the function [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists).

`isset` should be a bit faster *(as it's not a function)*, but will return false if the element exists and has the value `NULL`.

For example, considering this array :

```
$a = array(
    123 => 'glop', 
    456 => null, 
);
```

And those three tests, relying on `isset` :

```
var_dump(isset($a[123]));
var_dump(isset($a[456]));
var_dump(isset($a[789]));
```

The first one will get you (*the element exists, and is not null)* :

```
boolean true
```

While the second one will get you *(the element exists, but is null)* :

```
boolean false
```

And the last one will get you *(the element doesn't exist)* :

```
boolean false
```

On the other hand, using `array_key_exists` like this :

```
var_dump(array_key_exists(123, $a));
var_dump(array_key_exists(456, $a));
var_dump(array_key_exists(789, $a));
```

You'd get those outputs :

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
```

Because, in the two first cases, the element exists -- even if it's null in the second case. And, of course, in the third case, it doesn't exist.

For situations such as yours, I generally use `isset`, considering I'm never in the second case... But choosing which one to use is now up to you ;-)

For instance, your code could become something like this :

```
if (!isset(self::$instances[$instanceKey])) {
    $instances[$instanceKey] = $theInstance;
}
```

Comment: I have to complain 'cause `isset` is typo-unsafe. Called `$form = [1 => 5]; var_dump(isset($from[1]));` returns `false` since `$from` does not exist and you aren't even notified by `E_NOTICE`. Slower, but safer `array_key_exists` do the thing for me.

Answer (score 28):

array_key_exists() is SLOW compared to isset(). A combination of these two (see below code) would help.

It takes the performance advantage of isset() while maintaining the correct checking result (i.e. return TRUE even when the array element is NULL)

```
if (isset($a['element']) || array_key_exists('element', $a)) {
       //the element exists in the array. write your code here.
}
```

The benchmarking comparison: (extracted from below blog posts).

```
array_key_exists() only : 205 ms
isset() only : 35ms
isset() || array_key_exists() : 48ms
```

See 
http://thinkofdev.com/php-fast-way-to-determine-a-key-elements-existance-in-an-array/
and 
http://thinkofdev.com/php-isset-and-multi-dimentional-array/

for detailed discussion.

Comment: And, *isset* is also misleading. Why would a keyword named "is set" return *false* when a variable, or an array position, is actually set - even though it is set to *null*?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the function [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to do that.

For example,

```
$a=array("a"=>"Dog","b"=>"Cat");
if (array_key_exists("a",$a))
  {
  echo "Key exists!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Key does not exist!";
  }
```

PS : Example taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_key_exists.asp).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for this very thing.

```
$myArr = array("Name" => "Jonathan");
print (isset($myArr["Name"])) ? "Exists" : "Doesn't Exist" ;
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the PHP manual you can do this in two ways. It depends what you need to check.

If you want to check if the given key or index exists in the array use **array_key_exists**

```
<?php
    $search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
    if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
        echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
    }
?>
```

If you want to check if a value exists in an array use **in_array**

```
<?php
    $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
    if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
        echo "Got Irix";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the array_key_exists function.

Answer (score 3):

A little anecdote to illustrate the use of `array_key_exists`.

```
// A programmer walked through the parking lot in search of his car
// When he neared it, he reached for his pocket to grab his array of keys
$keyChain = array(
    'office-door' => unlockOffice(),
    'home-key' => unlockSmallApartment(),
    'wifes-mercedes' => unusedKeyAfterDivorce(),
    'safety-deposit-box' => uselessKeyForEmptyBox(),
    'rusto-old-car' => unlockOldBarrel(),
);

// He tried and tried but couldn't find the right key for his car
// And so he wondered if he had the right key with him.
// To determine this he used array_key_exists
if (array_key_exists('rusty-old-car', $keyChain)) {
    print('Its on the chain.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **array_keys** for number of occurrences

```
<?php
$array=array('1','2','6','6','6','5');
$i=count(array_keys($array, 6));
if($i>0)
 echo "Element exists in Array";
?>
```