# how to know whether key exists in Json string

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an array element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966169/how-to-check-if-an-array-element-exists)

apologize if i am wrong,I am new to PHP, Is there any way to find out whether key exists in `Json` string after decoding using `json_decode` function in PHP.

```
$json = {"user_id":"51","password":"abc123fo"};
```

Brief:

```
$json = {"password":"abc123fo"};
$mydata = json_decode($json,true);
user_id = $mydata['user_id'];
```

If json string doesn't consist of user_id,it throws an exception like `Undefined index user_id`,so is there any way to check whether key exists in Json string,Please help me,I am using `PHP 5.3 and Codeigniter 2.1 MVC` Thanks in advance

Comment: Reading the docs might help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Try:
`user_id = $mydata->user_id;`

You're now accessing a JSON 'Object' here.

Comment: if( isset( $mydata->password ) ){
    echo 'true';
 }

Answer (score 96):

IF you want to also check if the value is not `null` you can use `isset`

```
if( isset( $mydata['user_id'] ) ){
   // do something
}
```

i.e. the difference between `array_key_exists` and `isset` is that with

```
$json = {"user_id": null}
```

`array_key_exists` will return `true` whereas `isset` will return `false`

Comment: 'array_Key_exists' not working it is throwing error. array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, stdClass given

Comment: it's `array_key_exists`  not `array_Key_exists` (lowercase 'k') ... but the error says your second argument is not an array but an stdClass, i.e. you are most likely not passing `true` as the second argument to your `json_decode` function

Comment: Oh, I see. thanks

Answer (score 41):

You can try [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

It returns a boolean value, so you could search for it something like:

```
if(array_key_exists('user_id', $mydata)) {
    //key exists, do stuff
}
```