# How to check if a variable even exist after decode JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON string.

```
[
   {
     "name": "user_title",
     "value": "Bapak."
   },
   {
     "name": "user_firstname",
     "value": "Test"
   },
   {
     "name": "user_lastname",
     "value": "XXX"
   }
]
```

This string generated dynamically. It may has more or less. I use *JSON Decode* to process it in PHP.

```
$json_form      = json_decode($json_string,true);

$user_title     = $json_form[0]['value'];
$user_firstname = $json_form[1]['value'];
$user_lastname  = $json_form[2]['value'];
```

How do I check the variable user_title even exist in the string?

If it exist I should get the value but if not that means *$user_title = NULL*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to know whether key exists in Json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176293/how-to-know-whether-key-exists-in-json-string)

Comment: Also, just use their key, *not* their position, such as $json_form["user_title"] instead of $json_form[0], your code will break if the item positions are different

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider mapping your JSON into a key/value array using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column); then it is easy to check for the existence of a value. For example:

```php
$json_form = json_decode($json_string, true);
$values = array_column($json_form, 'value', 'name');

$user_title     = $values['user_title'];
$user_firstname = $values['user_firstname'];
$user_lastname  = $values['user_lastname'];

echo "title: $user_title\nfirst name: $user_firstname\nlast name: $user_lastname\n";
```

Output for your sample data is:

```
title: Bapak.
first name: Test
last name: XXX
```

It's also easy to add default values when a key is missing, for example:

```php
$user_title     = $values['user_title'] ?? '';
```