# How to check if an array value exists in PHP

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [array1] => Array
        (
            ...
        )

    [array2] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
)
```

How can I determine that `array2` exists ?

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966169/3933332

Comment: tried [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) already?

Comment: Or `array_key_exists()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php like the dupe suggests