# Undefined index at session data in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a login page in codeigniter where a user will give userid and password through an api(REST). When I run this page I get this error `"Undefined index: userId"`. That means session data not found. I've read some older post about this topic but can't find any perfect solution. So I post here. Here is my controller page:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');

        $userId = $_SESSION["userId"];
        $token = $_SESSION["token"];

        $this->load->view('loginPage');
    }


    public function loginFromPanel()    
    {

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        session_start();
        $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        if(isset($params) && !empty($params)){
            $userInfo = explode('&', $params);
            $token = explode('=', $userInfo[0]);
            $token = $token[1];


            $userId = explode('=', $userInfo[1]);
            $userId = $userId[1];

            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;

        }


        if($_SESSION['userId'] == "")
        {
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['userInfo'] = $userInfo;
            redirect('Instruction_page', 'refresh');
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the view page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Free HTML5 Website Template by freehtml5.co" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free html5, free template, free bootstrap, free website template, html5, css3, mobile first, responsive" />
    <meta name="author" content="freehtml5.co" />

    <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
    <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Popup API-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Popup Api-->

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="fh5co-loader"></div>

    <div id="page"> 
    <header id="fh5co-header" class="fh5co-cover js-fullheight" role="banner" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <div class="row main">

                <div class="main-login main-center">
                    <form  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Username"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginForm">Submit</div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
</div>

    <div id="fh5co-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>&copy; 2019 Total Gas</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gototop js-top">
        <a href="#" class="js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up22"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!--Popup API-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://user.onukit.com/6v0/js/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>


<script>
    $('#loginForm').click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val(); 
        var password = $('#password').val();
        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://api.onuserver.com/6v1.1/login_api/loginApi",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username+':'+password)
            },
            success: loginSuccess
        });
    });

    function loginSuccess(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        token = response.userToken.token;
        userId = response.userId;
        query_param = '?token='+token+'&userId='+userId;
  window.location.replace("http://demo.onuserver.com/CallLoyality/login/loginFromPanel/"+query_param);

    }

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the api:

````
/**
 * Example
 *
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Rest Server
 * @category    Controller
 * @author      Phil Sturgeon
 * @link        http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/
*/

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class loginApi extends REST_Controller
{

    function __construct() 
    {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }
        parent::__construct();              
        $this->isSuccessfulLogin = false;       
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }

    protected $rest_format   = 'application/json'; 

    function _perform_library_auth($username = '', $password = NULL)
    {

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

        $this->load->model('login_model');

        $isSuccessfulLoginArray= $this->login_model->getUserInfo($username, md5($password));

        $this->userData = $isSuccessfulLoginArray;


        if(empty($isSuccessfulLoginArray))
        {
            $responseData = array(
                    'status'    =>4200,
                    'success'   =>false,
                    'isActive'  =>false,
                    'reason'    =>'Username or password !'
            );

            $json_data = json_encode($responseData);

            $this->response($json_data ,200); 
        }else{
            return $this->userData = $isSuccessfulLoginArray;
        }
    }


    public function index_post()
    {

        $requestUserDetails = $this->userData;
        $userId = $requestUserDetails['id'];
        $parentId = $requestUserDetails['parent_user'];

        $token = $this->login_model->userToken($userId);


        $responseData['userId'] = $userId;
        $responseData['hashUserId'] = $this->encrypt->encode($userId);
        $responseData['parentId'] = $parentId;
        $responseData['userToken'] = $token;

        $json_data = json_encode($responseData);

        $this->response($json_data ,200);
    }   
}```

I'm using codeigniter 3. Please someone help me to find what's wrong in my code.
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966169/how-to-check-if-an-array-element-exists)

Comment: no it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Is the problem that the session value should be set but can't be found? Or that the session is not set and you're getting an "undefined index" error?